# using R probability

Tags: r

I am working on the subject of the French championship 2019, composed of 20 teams, and each team plays 38 times, if team A plays with team B, whatever the result, each team plays another time with another team determined by the draw.

If team A plays with team B, that means there are three possibilities 1/3 team A wins.

1/3 draw.

1/3 team A loses.

I have to look for the indifferent forecast of (probability of 1/3 team A wins, 1/3 draw and 1/3 team A loses) and that using R.

This is what I did me using R:

```
Binochampionnat = function(n = 38, p=1/3){  
  mu <- n * p ; sigm <- sqrt(n * p * (1-p))  
  probabino <- dbinom(0:n,n,p)  
  ak <- (0:(n+1) - mu) / sigm 
  etendue <- (ak[2]-ak[1])/2  
  bk <- ak - etendue 
  probagauss <- rep(NA, n+1)  
  for(i in 1:(n+1)) probagauss[i] <- pnorm(bk[i+1]) - pnorm(bk[i])  
  cat("binomiale distribution","\n") ; print(probabino)  
  cat("Gauss Distribution","\n") ; print(probagauss)  
  x <- t(as.matrix(data.frame(BINO=probabino,GAUSS=probagauss))) 
  barplot(x,beside=T,legend=T, names.arg = 0:n,      
          xlab = "Discrete variable values", ylab = "Probabilities") 
  title(paste("Approximation of the binomial law n =",n," ; p =",p))}
Binochampionnat(n = 38, p=1/3)
```

and I got a beautiful graph and results, that I could not stick here

What do you think? Is that correct?